# Angular UI Router named views using templateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application with two different tiers of functionality. Instead of constantly checking tiers within controllers, I have places where the functionality differs so wildly that I just have two separate templates and controllers.

In some situations, I use only `controllerProvider` to choose the different controller, in other places I use only `templateProvider` to choose a different template, in some places I use both. I'm having a problem with the last case.

Take the following state declaration:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('patient.orders.list', {
      url: '/orders/list',
      title: 'Orders',
      views: {
        'orders@patient.orders': {
          templateProvider: ['$rootScope','$templateCache','$http', function($rootScope, $templateCache, $http) {
            var templateName;

            if($rootScope.tier === 'SWIFT') {
              templateName = 'views/patients/patient/orders/list.swift.tmpl.html';
            } else {
              templateName = 'views/patients/patient/orders/list.ik.tmpl.html';
            }

            var template = $templateCache.get(templateName);

            if(template) {
              return template;
            }

            return $http
              .get(templateName)
              .then(function(response) {
                template = response.data;
                $templateCache.put(templateName, template);
                return template;
              });
          }],
          controllerProvider: ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
            if($rootScope.tier === 'SWIFT') {
              return 'PatientOrdersSwiftListCtrl';
            } else {
              return 'PatientOrdersIkListCtrl as vm';
            }
          }]
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        treatmentHistories: ['TreatmentHistory', '$stateParams', function (TreatmentHistory, $stateParams) {
          var params = {},
            options = {bypassCache: true, endpoint: 'patients/' + $stateParams.patientid + '/treatmenthistory'};
          TreatmentHistory.ejectAll();
          return TreatmentHistory.findAll(params, options)
            .then(_.identity,
            // on error
            function (error) {
              console.log('Error encountered fetching treatmentHistories:' + error);
              return 'fetchError';
            });
        }],
        discontinueReasons: ['DiscontinueReason', function (DiscontinueReason) {
          return DiscontinueReason.findAll()
            .then(_.identity,
            // on error
            function (error) {
              console.log('Error encountered fetching discontinue reasons:' + error);
              return 'fetchError';
            });
        }]
      }
    })
```

This works great! The problem arises with the `views/patients/patient/orders/list.ik.tmpl.html` template having a named view:

```
<div layout="row">
  <filter-pane class="padding-light">
     <md-list>
       <md-list-item ng-repeat="treatmentHistory in vm.treatmentHistories">
         <h3 ui-sref="patient.orders.list.plan({regimenOrderId: treatmentHistory.regimenOrder.id})">{{treatmentHistory.regimenOrder.name}}</h3>
       </md-list-item>
     </md-list>
  </filter-pane>
  <div layout="row" ui-view="plan"></div>
</div>
```

And then then the state declaration that calls upon that named view:

```
.state('patient.orders.list.plan', {
      url: '/{regimenOrderId}',
      params: {
        regimenOrderId: null
      },
      views: {
        'plan@patient.orders.list': {
          templateUrl: 'views/patients/patient/orders/orders.treatmentplan.tmpl.html',
          controller: 'PatientOrdersTreatmentPlanCtrl'
        }
      }
 })
```

When I have `patient.orders.list` use `templateProvider` and `controllerProvider`, then `patient.orders.list.plan` will not render. When I switch `patient.orders.list` to use just `templateUrl` and `controller` everything works just fine!

I don't want to have to have two separate states and handle the switching logic in a parent state, I like being able to use the provider syntax.

Comment: Sounds like you've found a bug

Comment: @Phil I think you may be right, but as UI-Router is rapidly working towards a 1.0 release - this may not be in their pipeline to fix. I'm going to log an issue there, but want to get this example working in a Plunkr first.

Comment: This bug went away after upgrading to Angular ^1.5 ... not sure why. I hate those kinds of bugs!